# HPE Raid logical drives not showing in Windows

Tags: windows, hp-smart-array, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to provision a new server with Windows Server 2019. I have used Intelligent Provisioning to create three arrays:

**HPE Proliant ML110 - HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10**

- 2 x SSD Raid 0 - O/S
- 2 x SATA Raid 0 - Data
- 4 x SSD Raid 5 - Database

Here you can see this in Storage Adminitrator:
[image: Storage Administrator]

However, when I use Computer Management to initialize and create partitions on the new logical drives, they do not appear:
[image: Computer Management]

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I've removed the arrays and recreated them with multiple reboots along the way, but no matter what I do, Windows will just not see them. Thanks.

Comment: Try "Rescan Disks" in the Disk Management console.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought but it doesn't detect them on a rescan or reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It was the controller firmware (v1.4). HPE support sent me the latest SPP (v1.99) and everything is now fine.